# How to set templates in my Java Constructor?

Tags: java, bluej

I have a string called CardRefernce that takes form of "CardID NUM". In my constructor I simply want the user to insert an integer that replaces "NUM" in "CardID NUM"

I have already set the parameter to int but if i were to return CardReference it wouldn't take form of "CardID NUM"

```
    public LibraryCard(int MaxBorrowedBooks, int CardID)
    {
    // initialise instance variables
    MaxBorrowedBooks = BookLimit;
    CardID = CardReference;
    CurrentBooks = 0; 
    }
```

If i were to return CardReference I would expect it to return "CardID" followed by some sort of integer.

Comment: Your initializations are backwards (except the last one), and your question is unclear.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are always written in camelCase, for example `MaxBorrowedBooks` should be `maxBorrowedBooks`.